# Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than WSGIRequest

Tags: python, django, django-views, mod-wsgi

I'm making a web app using Django 1.11, Apache 2.2, and mod_wsgi all using Python 2.7. I'm having an issue rendering my page. **The full traceback is**,

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://website.com/~user/irtf/

Django Version: 1.11.1
Python Version: 2.7.13
Installed Applications:
['irtf.apps.IrtfConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mod_wsgi.server']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/path/irtf_website/mysiteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/path/irtf_website/mysiteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/path/irtf_website/mysiteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/path/irtf_website/mysite/irtf/views.py" in index
  18.         return HttpResponse(template.render(request))

File "/home/path/irtf_website/mysiteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  64.         context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)

File "/home/path/irtf_website/mysiteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in make_context
  287.         raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)

Exception Type: TypeError at /irtf/
Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than WSGIRequest.
```

My **views.py** is,

```
def index(request):
        template = loader.get_template('irtf/index.html')

        return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

It might not matter but my template for this page just consists of text and links.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Which is because the first [parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render) is supposed to be a dictionary. You had perhaps mixed this up with the render short cut

```
template = loader.get_template('irtf/index.html')
return HttpResponse( template.render({}, request))
```

To use the [render shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead

```
return render(request,'irtf/index.html')
```

Comment: Thank you. I got confused because in the tutorial page on views (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/) HttpResponse is used without dicts getting passed. Is the documentation not correct or is there a difference that I'm not seeing?

Comment: There it's the render shortcut that is used without a dictionary. In some places they have used the `render` shortcut in other `template.render` they look similar but have different behaviour. THe tutorial isn't wrong but it maybe confusing.

Comment: It's not HttpResponse that is throwing the error here, it's the Template.render method that is throwing the exception. The method signature for [Template.render](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/backends/django.py#L58) either requires context and request to be specified as keyword arguments, i.e. `template.render(request=request, context=context)` or the request and context should be provided as positional arguments, i.e. `template.render(None, request)`.  Once the call to render is fixed it will return a string which is a valid first argument to HttpResponse.

Comment: Sorry there was indeed a typo in my answer but the first parameter is indeed the dictionary